# Sign of eigenvalues of a 2 x 2 matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How can see what the signs of the eigenvalues of the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 198 & 261 \\ 486 & 261 \end{pmatrix}$ are directly without calculating the roots of the characteristic polynomial? Both entries in the second diagonal aregreater than those in the main diagonal, can we use that?

Comment: What is the sign of the determinant? What do you learn from that about the signs of the eigenvalues? Note that you don't even need to calculate the determinant to answer this question, thanks to the special form of the second column.

Answer (score 2):

We can use Descartes's sign-rule.

The characteristic polynomial has the form $$x^2+ax+b$$ with negative $a$ and negative $b$ because the trace is obviously positive and the determinant negative (Can easily be seen)

The signs are $+,-,-$

We have one sign-change, so we can conclude that exactly one root is positive.

If we replace $x$ by $-x$ , we get $$x^2-ax+b$$

Now, the signs are $+,+,-$

Again, we have one sign change , so we have exactly one negative root as well.

Comment: What do you mean by sign-change?

Comment: We look at the signs of the coefficients of the polynial (zeros are not considered). Descartes's rule states that the number of positive roots is either the number of sign changes or an even number smaller (considering multiplicity)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The Determinant is clearly negative.

Comment: @Arthur Yes, it shows there are two eigenvalues: a polynomial $x^2+ax+b$ with $b<0$ has positive determinant. Moreover, the roots must have different signs (Viète's formula).

Comment: @egreg plus the $\Delta$ must be greater than $4 \times 486 \times 261$ a priori.

Comment: @Arthur As I said, not when the determinant is negative.

Comment: @egreg You're right. I was too focused along the lines of "but what about non-diagonalisable matrices?" but apparently there are none with negative determinant.